# Lambda Scheduled Trigger not working well

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function which I intend to execute every 20 minute. I have created a Cloudwatch scheduled rule for it. But the problem is its not executing exactly in the interval of 20 minutes. Sometimes it executes twice or thrice in a minute, sometimes it takes hours! What could be the problem?

Comment: Review your Lambda logs.  The most likely scenario is that function is being executed, but not working properly... but you have not explained how you exactly you determined that it is not working as expected.

Comment: You can also review the **Next 10 Trigger Dates** on the Cloudwatch page to confirm your triggers are happening when you expect them to.

Comment: I refered to the cloudtrail records!! It shows that the function isnot being executed as expected. Maybe I should try logging with cloudwatch logs?